# No ProjectInfo.xml files were found. Generation of the sonar-properties file failed

Tags: c#, msbuild, sonarqube

I am trying to configure my project to send some analysis data to SonarQube server. I run the `MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner.exe begin` command followed by `msbuild`. My solution has 3 projects libraries and 1 unit test project.

The begin command and msbuild run without any errors but the end command outputs the following error and there is no data that is posted to the SonarQube server.

```
C:\solutions> "C:\SonarQube Runner\MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner.exe" end
MSBuild SonarQube Runner Bootstrapper 1.0.2.0
Default properties file was found at C:\SonarQube Runner\SonarQube.Analysis.xml
Loading analysis properties from C:\SonarQube Runner\SonarQube.Analysis.xml
Post-processing started.
MSBuild SonarQube Runner Post-processor 1.0.2.0
No ProjectInfo.xml files were found. Possible causes: you specified an invalid build configuration or the custom MSBuild analysis targets were not imported. Generation of the sonar-properties file failed. Unable to complete SonarQube analysis.
13:58:45.786  Creating a summary markdown file...
Post-processing failed. Exit code: 1
```

Now sure what I'm doing wrong. Can you please assist with the same? Please let me know if I should provide more information.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you're running MSBuild version 12 or 14 to build & analyze your project, and also make sure that you're running the `begin` and `end` commands of the SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild as well as the `msbuild` command from the same folder.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, it turned out that I didn't have MSBuild 12.0 installed. Once installed it it worked flawlessly :)

You can get it here http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40760